# How to assign [(ngModel)] with an empty/null/undefined object? Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic3

I want to assign [(ngModel)] inside my .html code to an object which is empty (null or undefined), but it gives error of ***_co.object is null.***
There are 2 cases, 1st when my object has value, 2nd when it does not. First case ngModel works fine, but when it comes to second, it gives error of being null. With elvis(?) operator i tried, it does not help.

**Problem was solved !! THank you all**

**My .ts page**

```
profile: Profile = {

          fullName: '',
          email: '',
          address: '', 
      };
```

**My .html page**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Full Name:</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="profile.fullName"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**ERROR TypeError: "_co.profile is null"**

Comment: Where is `_co`?

Comment: secure it witha  *ngIf

Comment: no problem with this code, post full code please.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I dont know what is _co. It gives such an error which refers to 'profile' object.

Comment: @Domi What do you mean? If I say *ngIf="profile!=null" then it won't display the form, but I need to fill the form in order to give those values to 'profile' object

Comment: @fatemefazli Thank you, I found mistake in another place and solved it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys. I found my mistake to be in another place. I somehow was re-asigning the 'profile' object in **ngOnInit** from empty to undefined. Like so:

```
ngOnInit(){  
//code...
 if(!this.profile){
      this.profile = {} as Profile; //here was the mistake which I accidentally made.
      //and it was assigning my object to null
   }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You always need to secure getting properties of an object. Or in the future you can face unexpected problems.

Either use ngIf

```
<ion-item *ngIf="profile">
  <ion-label>Full Name:</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="profile.fullName"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

or make it optional

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Full Name:</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="profile?.fullName"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

if you have compilation error, when using optional chaining, you need to separate property and event bidding

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Full Name:</ion-label>
  <ion-input [ngModel]="profile.fullName" (ngModelChange)="profile?.fullName = $event"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Timothy, I understand the need to secure getting the properties but can you please elaborate on the "unexpected problems" - is there a documented list anywhere that I can refer?

Comment: @sikanderBabwani the biggest "unexpected problem" with angular is this one https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/ . It might cause infinite loops and many other issues. Highly recommend to knowledge yourself about it

Comment: Making it optional throws compilation error. Can use optionals in with ngModel

Comment: @zulkarnainshah in this case you need to separate property and event bindings..

Answer (score 0):

When you declare profile you should add all the children this will stop it being undefined.

```
export class Foo {

public profile:any = { 
        fullName='',
        foo = '',
        bar = ''
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

When your binding is to a property of a nullable object you can protect against errors when the object is null by creating a setter and getter and binding to that property alias.

For example, instead of

```
[(ngModel)]="model[`${this.field.key}_selectedObject`]"
```

change to

```
[(ngModel)]="fieldModel"
```

Then in your ts code add

```
public get fieldModel(): any  {
   if (!this.model) return null;
   return this.model[`${this.field.key}_selectedObject`];
}
public set fieldModel(value: any) {
   if (!this.model) return;
   this.model[`${this.field.key}_selectedObject`] = value;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For anyone having this error on angular 10+.
Do this in your tsconfig file

```
  "strict": true,
  "strictNullChecks": false
```

and then here is an example of how you could use it in your property binding

```
<div>
  <label>Street Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street"
   [(ngModel)]="user.address.street">
</div>
```

assuming your model looks like this

```
User {
 address?: {
    street?: string,
    city?: string,
    province?: string
  }
}
```